# How to optimize a function that contains an integral in R or Python?

Tags: python, r, function, optimization, integral

First time asking a question here, but definitely have been benefiting from browsing all the amazing answers to other questions.

So, the problem is I am trying to optimize a function via MLE in R(or Python works too), and the part of the function is an integral containing the parameters that I am estimating. The function looks like this:

[The log-likelihood function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLhZs.png)

where, F(w) is the CDF of a log-normal distribution with unknown mean and sigma to be estimated, so is lambda and eta. All other parameters are known, including w*. I attempted to estimate this function using the mle command in R. But it couldn't go through due to the integral part. Can anyone help me on this? My codes are below. Thanks so much!

[Definitions of f(w) and F(w)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISkSM.png)

My codes that didn't work:

```
  func <- function(mu, sigma_w){
F_w = (-.5*(((log(w_star)-mu)/sigma_w))^2)
```

}

```
ll <- function(lambda,sigma_w,eta,mu) {
  R <- N*log(lambda) + N_u*log(1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(integrate(func,lower = -Inf, upper = w_star, rel.tol=1e-5)$value)) - lambda*1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(integrate(func,lower = -Inf, upper = w_star, rel.tol=1e-5)$value)*sum(T_ui) + N_u*log(eta) + sum(log(1/(sigma_w*w_i)*1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-.5*((log(w_i-mu)/sigma_w)^2)))) - N*log(eta+lambda*1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(integrate(integrate(func,lower = -Inf, upper = w_star, rel.tol=1e-5)$value)))
  return(R)                           
}

fit <-mle(ll,start = list(lambda =0, sigma_w = 0, eta =0, mu = 0))
```

Error message:

```
Error in f(x, ...) : argument "sigma_w" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a beautiful example of the use of closure in R (functions that return functions). They serve precisely for MLE, try this code with your values:

````
library(stats4)

ll <- function(lambda, eta, sigma_w, mu, w_start, w_i, N, N_u )
{
  # fix the others params
  w_start <- w_start
  mu <- mu
  T_ui <- T_ui #your sample
  w_i <- w_i #another sample
  sigma_w <- sigma_w
  N <- N
  N_u <- N_u 
  #return another funtion
  function(lambda, eta)
  {
    F_star <- log( plnorm( q = w_star,
                           meanlog = mu, sdlog = sigma_w) ) 
    ll.scalar <- N * lambda + N_u*log( F_star) - lambda * F_star * sum(T_ui) +
      N_u* log(eta) + sum( log( dlnorm(x = w_i))) - N * log(eta + F_star)

    return(-ll.scalar) # negative for use in stats4::mle
  }
}

# your values example
w_star <- 1
mu <- 1
T_ui <- c(1,2,3) #your sample
w_i <- c(1,2,3)/10 #another sample
sigma_w <- 1
N <- 1 
N_u <- 1 
# You build the function with the closure
myLL <- ll(lambda , eta, sigma_w , mu, w_star , w_i , N, N_u  )


# now optimitation 

result <- mle(myLL, start= list(lambda=0,  eta=0))
result

```
````

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The mean and variance of that log-normal distribution are unknown, so they should be estimated alongside lambda and eta. Can you please reconsider your answer? I know this should be very close. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, I got the following error message when calling the MLE function: 

Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
In addition: Warning message:
In log(F_star) : NaNs produced

Hope you could think about this too.

Comment: this is a similar case. Can you please edit your question a give the sample that you are using ?, the values of w_star, N, N_u and the vectors T_ui and w_i